# Distance Along a Curve

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Given $f(x)=10^3( \sin^2(\frac{33\pi}{x})+\sin^2(x\pi))-10$, what is the distance along the curve between $[a,b]$ in the form of $h(a,b)$? If in some interval $[m,n]$ a subster of $[a,b]$ $f$ is all negative, I want the distance in that interval to be negative and subtracted from the entire $h(a,b)$. I also want the same thing applied to $g(x)=|f(x)|$.

Comment: Where does it come from?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Another function-- trying to find the path along an curve, and this was one of the steps.

Comment: Mathematica,Rubi and Maple can't find solution.

Comment: maybe you got the path integral wrong? give the real question

Comment: @trula What do you mean by the real question?

Comment: the question where this integral comes from

Comment: @trula Posted the full thing.

Comment: you said " this was one of the steps." ! so could it be wrong step?

Comment: @trula No, no, this is the full problem.